# Seam 2.2 and JBoss Tools 3.1, Why JBoss Tools doesnt work anymore?

Tags: eclipse, seam, jboss-tools

I've downloaded the new Seam 2.2GA but it doesn't work with the current version of JBoss Tools 3.1.

Anyone had any luck making those work together again?

Is there a new version of JBoss Tools out somewhere? maybe a beta, something you can get back to generating Seam projects in eclipse, rather than using the seam-gen.

Thx in advance,

Rodrigo Dellacqua

Answer (score 0):

According to the [download site,](http://labs.jboss.com/tools/download), 3.1.0.M2 is the latest development version. You could try the [nightly build](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/nightly/trunk/) of 3.1.0.M3 for Eclipse 3.5 to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What Is not working for you exactly? 
Since seam 2.2 was released after the latest toolsrelease weof course Dont have The version listed but you should just be able to use it A's a 2.1 of seam.

The nightly builds have full 2.2 support so try that out if you feel Line it. 
And for future reference using JBoss tools forum would e a much more natural place for such a question :)